# Export pandas DataFrame to csv file using ArcGIS Pro script tool

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arcgis, arcpy

I've created a script tool in ArcGIS Pro that asks the user to select a csv file, and then reads that csv file into a pandas DataFrame and performs some calculations.  I'd like to be able to export a new csv file after the calculations are complete in the same folder as the input csv file.

For example, the user selects the input csv file from (C:\Users\Luis\GIS\input.csv).
I'd like to export a new csv at the end of the script to (C:\Users\Luis\GIS\output.csv)

The parameter that reads in the user input is set up as follows:

```
input_csv = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
```

The data type for this parameter is File is the Tool Properties in ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to get the folder the input file is in and the input_csv parameter is an absolute path you can use the following

```
input_csv = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output_csv = input_csv.split('\\')[:-1]
output_csv = '\\'.join(output_csv + ['output.csv'])
```

Then save your DataFrame using the new filepath

```
df.to_csv(output_csv)
```